# UISearchBarDelegate and UITableView not working together?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have a table view controller with a standard UISearchBar

I want to replace the first row in the table with the text in the search bar as it gets typed.
I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    // results is a mutable array with an empty string at index 0
    [[self results] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:searchText];   
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

If I log the results array to the console it is correctly replacing the object,
but it is not getting picked up by the table view.

I have the table data source set up as per usual:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self results] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[[self results] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

If I just use insertObjectAtIndex: or insertObject: it does show up the results.  Just not when I'm trying to replace first object.
Help please! :)

Comment: Try killing this line:   `if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }`  . The reason I say this is that you are alloc-ing each cell.

Comment: Here's a post that I had stashed away:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286669/iphone-how-to-purge-a-cached-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out.
Really stupid too....
The searchBar was covering the first row of the tableView, so I couldn't see it updating.
Doh.

Answer (score -1):

Try killing this line: `if (cell == nil) { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }` . The reason I say this is that you are alloc-ing each cell.

Here's a post that I had stashed away:  [iPhone: How to purge a cached UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286669/iphone-how-to-purge-a-cached-uitableviewcell)

Comment: How are you implementing your tableview datasource delegate methods?